# nemo-share doesn't work

Tags: nautilus, samba, shared-folders, nemo

I have installed `samba`, `nemo-share`, `nautilus-share`.

I can't find any share option anywhere in `nemo` or `nautilus`. It's not in the right click menu. It's not in the drop down menus. It's not in folder properties.

I'm using Lubuntu 16.10 :

- `nemo-share` from `ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon`
- `nautilus-share` from normal repository

Sharing does work (editing `smb.conf` manually).

`nemo-share` and `nautilus-share` don't work.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you install from the repositories? Did you restart nemo after installing nemo-share? Nemo-share should add the "Sharing Options" entry to the context menu (right-click) for directories in nemo.